# Magento 2 Sizes showing in a wrong order for configurable products

Tags: configurable-swatches, magento-2.2.5

I have just upgraded my Magento to 2.2.5 via composer.

I realized that the Sizes from the dropdown on product page is displaying in a wrong order, see screenshot.

[image]

But in Admin, under product attributes, the sizes are listed in a right order.

What went wrong?